# Fancy box with carousel/sliding

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, fancybox

I have a problem facing related fancy box. I want to achieve UI: images in fancybox with carousel option to slide the items.

Here is the UI i need to achieve:

[image: UI]

here is my code:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css'>


<div class="gallery-section">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="nospace">
    <div class="gallery-box">

      <div class="box vertical">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/2.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/2.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="box vertical">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/8.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/8.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/3.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/3.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="box vertical">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/4.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/4.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="box vertical">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/6.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/6.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/7.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/7.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="assets/img/portfolio/5.png" data-fancybox="gallery1">
          <img src="assets/img/portfolio/5.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js'></script>
```

Can somebody help me to sort out this problem. Thank you. If you have any question let me know.

Comment: Please provide your attempt and details on why it didn't work - SO is not a free programming service

Comment: @Pete i have posted my code. sorry for this.

Comment: i want carousel to slide like owl  carousel as shown in the pic @Pete

Comment: See this sample on how to combine Fancybox v3 with some carousel - https://web.archive.org/web/20210325170940/https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-6 But for v4, it is very simple, see https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/#combine-with-carousel

Comment: @Janis the problem occurs when i have to make it grid. how to make it grid like the image i attached ?

Comment: So, your actual question is how to create image grid, right? There are plenty of options, you could use HTML table, you could also create using CSS flexbox or grid.

Comment: @Janis i am asking how to make grid gallery with carousel slider? isnt it clear?

Comment: i am already using fancy box option in site. just want to add carousel indicator to slider the grid images to next. i tried in fancybox playground and couldn't achieve that.

Comment: So, you need help to 1) create image grid; 2) move it inside carousel slide element. Right? Here is one possible solution - https://fancyapps.com/playground/1ZP

Comment: @Janis thank you so much. :) can you please post your as answer. i will accept your solution so other people can take benefit. thank you again so much

Comment: @Janis could you explain this  w-10/12 max-w-xl? i find little bit confusing here

Comment: It is just a Tailwind thing, you can ignore that. It sets max width for the Carousel.

Comment: @Janis thank a tons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241835/discussion-between-thedebuggger-and-janis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple elements inside carousel slide element. Then, for example, use CSS to create two columns. Example using Tailwind CSS and Carousel 4:

```
<div class="carousel__slide grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
  <a href="https://lipsum.app/id/1/900x600" data-fancybox="gallery">
    <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/1/600x400" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://lipsum.app/id/2/900x600" data-fancybox="gallery">
    <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/600x400" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: please check this link